# Why teradata fastload is so slow?

Tags: java, teradata

I tried to upload 3MB really small csv file with 30,000 rows and 4 columns . It took me more than an hour

```
cUrl = "jdbc:odbc:DSN; TYPE=FASTLOAD" ;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(cUrl, username, password);
String sql = "insert into Transactions(custID, transaction_date, amount, desc) values(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    for ( ... ) 
    {
        ps.setString(1, custID);
        ps.setString(2, tran_date);
        ps.setString(3, amount);
        ps.setString(4, desc);
        ps.addBatch(); 
    }


    ps.executeBatch();
```

The `addBatch` runs very smoothly. Ones I get to the `ps.executeBatch();` line it takes it forever . It took over an hour to upload a 3 MB csv file with 30,000 rows . Is it the way it is supposed to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading 30.000 row should run in a few seconds as maximum.

You're still using the wrong connection string, there's no support for the FastLoad protocol in ODBC, TYPE=FASTLOAD is probably silently ignored.

What's the Primary Index of the Transactions table? A bad PI plus a SET table might result in slow loading.

Comment: Thank you. I do not specify primary index. What do you mean by a `SET` table ?

Comment: I guess you are right about odbc , so i try to switch to regular but get `single sign on not supported for mechanism TD2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237566/single-sing-on-is-not-supported-for-mechanism-td2

Comment: If you don't specify a Primary Index it will probably default to the first column, which might be a real bad choice. What does a **SHOW TABLE transactions;** return?  SET table means no duplicate rows allowed, which might result in a large amount of duplicate row checks. You can see SET or MULTISET with a SHOW TABLE, too.

Comment: I am using `CREATE TABLE myTable AS ( xxx, xxy, ..) ` i do not specidy primary keys . And my rows have duplicates . If i create some `id` primary index that would be `1,2,3 ` , this will increase the data set's size . But will this result in faster upload ?

Comment: You don't need to specify a Primary Key, but you should specify a Primary Index based on number of rows per value and join/where-access. And if you really have fully duplicate rows you can't load them with FastLoad (unless you specify "No Primary Index", but this might be bad for further processing)