# Single sign on is not supported for mechanism TD2

Tags: java, teradata

I got this `Single sign on is not supported for mechanism TD2` error when i was trying to connect to teradata .

In C# i had a similar problem, which i solved by adding `connectionStringBuilder.AutheticationMechanism = "LDAP"`

How can I solve this issue in java

I read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/auth_mechs.html) but could not solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "LOGMECH=LDAP" in JDBC.

Btw, there's a JDBC manual with lots of examples in it:

http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/reference/jdbc-driver

Comment: great tutorial this is just what i needed . and by the way you were right about it was silently ignored and that i needed to use the direct connection